# regular expression not work in android

Tags: java, regex, validation, android-edittext

Hi I want to match first name character by character but this make a error , this is my code:

```
int length = input.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    char ch = input.charAt(i);
    String regex ="^[_\\s]||[آ-ی]$";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher(ch);
```

and this is my complete code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    String input;
    String result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               input = editText.getText().toString();
                check_reg();
            }
        });

    }
    public  boolean check_reg(){
        int length = input.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            char ch = input.charAt(i);
            String regex ="^[_\\s]||[آ-ی]$";
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher(ch);
            if (matcher.find( ))
            {
                result = matcher.group();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is a image of my problem:

[image]

Comment: I guess its java thing?

Comment: From what I've read in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), the `pattern.matcher()` method only accepts types `String` and `CharSequence`...not `char`

Comment: Why check character by character? You may use `^[_\\sآ-ی]+$` to check it as a whole string. `input.matches("[_\\sآ-ی]+")`

Comment: @nazanin ask Jawad Ysari

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing a `char` type to the `<Pattern>.matcher()` method, which only accepts types `String` or `CharSequence`. [Here are the docs that explain it.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
char ch = input.charAt(i);
String regex ="^[_\\s]||[آ-ی]$";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher(ch);
```

All you need to do to fix the error is to convert the `char ch` variable to a string when you pass it to the `matcher()` method.

```
char ch = input.charAt(i);
String regex ="^[_\\s]||[آ-ی]$";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(Character.toString(ch));
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you that you must pass a `String` to the method `matcher()`.  You can not pass a `char` to it.

You can create a String of length one if that is what you want.

You can use the regular expression in a more natural way and let it do the matching for you.  For example:

```
public  boolean check_reg(){
    String regex ="^(?:[_\\s]||[آ-ی])+$";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find( ))
        {
            result = matcher.group();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
}
```

This pattern will match, character-by-character, the entire input string.